# OpenVPN: Client-side Internet connection doesnt work in one local network, but in another does

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

In our company, we now established a **OpenVPN** connection to a remote network infrastructure.

Here comes the **problem**:

I'm accessing the VPN with the same machine (Arch btw) from 2 networks. From both I can flawlessly connect to the VPN. **But only in one of those, I can access the internet.**

Do you have a clue, what the reason could be, that the rerouting of the traffic is network-dependent? And how can I fix it?

The network, where the internet doesn't work is my private one, so I have complete control over it. On the OpenVPN server conf, I have little influence (would need to call our sys admin), but the conf I'll add here!

This is my `user.conf`

```
client

dev tun
remote 52.136.xxx.xxx 1194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server

cipher AES-256-CBC

verb 3
```

I think, the IP routes as well as the netstat log might be helpful for finding the error:

`ip route` without VPN (internet works):

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.13 metric 202 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-f54884879766 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.13 metric 202
```

`netstat -r -n` without VPN (internet works)

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp2s0
```

`ip route` with VPN (no internet):

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.17 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.13 metric 202 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.17 dev tun0 
10.8.0.17 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.18 
52.136.xxx.xxx via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.17 dev tun0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.13 metric 202
```

`netstat -r -n` with VPN (no internet)

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface    MSS   Window irtt
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.17       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0     0     0      0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 enp2s0   0     0      0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.17       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0     0     0      0
10.8.0.17       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0     0     0      0
52.136.xxx.xxx  _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp2s0   0     0      0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.17       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0     0     0      0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 enp2s0   0     0      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less, I achieved what I want -- at least, to achieve that VPN AND internet is working.

I achieved this, by not routing the internet traffic over the VPN. 
This I did via adding this to the client's configuration

```
route 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 64.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 128.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 192.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
```

For more details, I'm referring to the site, where I have this from https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=27618